# Cannot resolve file 'signup'

Tags: python, html, django

I am newbie to Django and i need help to solve this problem. It states that cannot resolve file'signup'.

```
<h3>Create your account!</h3>
    <form method="post" action="/signup">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Create A Username (use only letters and numbers)" Required>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a button to submit.

```
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: where should i put this code?

Comment: See my answer, copy paste the code from answer into your code and try again

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
<h3>Create your account!</h3>
<form method="post" action="/signup">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Create A Username (use only letters and numbers)" Required>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
   </form>
```

Your form was not a **valid one** and was not submitting anything.

Comment: it still doesn't works

Comment: Are you sure the url is valid ? What are you trying to achieve ? Form does not work like that in Django, you suppose to pass a form variable

Comment: i am trying to achieve signup page in web

Comment: Yes but you are using a framework and form is a big part of Django, you obisously do not understand the basic principles of it, so before going any further have a look at the step by step tutorial from Django : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/